# Installing brackets

Tags: command-line, software-installation, ide

I'm trying to install brackets.
i've used the `dpkg` command.
i've checked `/opt` and there's a new folder called Brackets.What should i do with it in order to run brackets?
When i type `brackets` in terminal, i get this:

```
/usr/bin/brackets: /usr/lib/libstdc++ .50.6:version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/brackets/lib/libcef.so)
/usr/bin/brackets: /lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /opt/brackets/lib/libcef.so)
```

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @A.B. The Version Is 10.10

Comment: I believe, you have no chance. Upgrade your system.

Answer (score 1):

If your Ubuntu version is 10.10, then you will have no chance in downloading Brackets as it is intended for newer systems.